# Keep heading type with number when adding a cross reference in Word 2011

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2011, cross-reference

I've got a document I'm cleaning up for a customer that they want fully cross-referenced with internal hyperlinks.  Headings for the main areas are in the format of:

> Phase I: [description of phase here]

Embedding the whole title is a bit problematic, because if I trim it down to just `Phase I` it restores the whole `Phase I: [description of phase here]` for every reference.

As a workaround I tried creating a custom numbering format for the appropriate heading along the lines of the following:

> Phase #:

And it has no problem automatically numbering things.  Unfortunately, this also hid it from the headings list for cross-referencing purposes (couple preliminary sections also use Heading 1), and when I told it to put in a cross-reference using the heading's number, all I ended up with was `i`—not `Phase I`, which I was expecting.

Is there a way to get this kind of numbering system going and have word embed the cross-reference as `Phase #` from the outset?  If not, even tweaking with the field codes is fine, so long as I can get the right result.

**TL;DR:** I'm trying to do a cross-reference as "number with label" the way you would for figures, but with headings instead.